# Firefox, Chromium, Opera - A lot of IO on my SSD (PCIe NVMe) on Lubuntu

Tags: linux, firefox, chromium, opera, lubuntu

I hope this forum is the right one to ask, as this is related to web browsers and writing behaviours on SSD.

I’m on `Lubuntu 23.04` with

```
Linux MYCOMPUTER 6.2.0-20-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr 6 07:48:48 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

On installation of `Lubuntu` I chose `No Swap`, I thought this is all that has to be done so eveything is done in `RAM`, applications don’t write there stuff to disk but keep everything for a session in `RAM`, only stuff that I wish to save to disk (modified files, downloaded files, etc.) is saved to disk.

I posted regarding a change to reduce writing to disk in the `Lubuntu` forum https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lubuntu-23-04-a-lot-of-io-on-my-ssd-pcie-nvme/4258

Recently I see a lot of IO on my `SSD` (`PCEe NvME`), more or less seen by coincidence as I just wanted to see how the health of my SSD is, never checked it on `Linux` before.

`Google` pointed me to a lot of posts on sites regarding haeavy IO by the web browsers. I checked first `Firefox`, `iotop` showed me continuous writing to disk every 15 secs. I found some changes to be done vie `about:config`

```
browser.cache.disk.enable = false 
browser.sessionstore.interval = 6480000
browser.sessionstore.interval.idle = 6480000
```

I found also

```
browser.cache.disk.smart_size.enabled = false
browser.cache.offline.enable = false  
browser.cache.disk_cache_ssl = false 
browser.cache.memory.enable = true
browser.cache.memory.capacity = -1
```

It reduced writing to disk, `Firefox` felt to be faster also, but still there is writing to disk which I assume is not necessary.

I put `Firefox` aside to check then for `Chromium` (the same should apply to `Opera` I believe), and I found these to run `Chromium` from terminal (`qterminal`)

```
chromium 
--disk-cache-size=1
--media-cache-size=1
--disable-gpu-program-cache
--disable-gpu-shader-disk-cache
--v8-cache-options=none
```

It reduced writing to disk, `Chromium` and `Opera` felt to be faster also, but still there is writing to disk which I assume is not necessary.

I then found these

```
--skia-font-cache-limit-mb=1
--skia-resource-cache-limit-mb=1
```

and it looks like it reduced writing to disk too, but still not enough I would guess.

Regarding topic `Skia`, I coundn't find anything similar for `Firefox`, only 1 entry in `about:config`

```
gfx.content.skia-font-cache-size = 5
```

which I don't know if to change or not, if a change would improve something.

I don't know if all of these properties are needed or some don't help at all, maybe some other have to be applied too, for all 3 web browsers.

Which one of `Firefox`, `Chromium` and `Opera` are best suited for streaming video? I hope that none of these web browsers is writing video streaming data to disk.

How to improve things further to reduce IO to disk, instead more shall happen in `RAM`?
I usually see `RAM` usage from about `2GB` to `4GB`, mostly around `3GB`, I do have `16GB`.

`Firefox` (currently `113.0.2 (64-bit`)) is shipped with `Lubuntu` installation, `Chromium` (`113.0.5672.126 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)`) and `Opera` (`99.0.4788.13`) I have installed via `Discover`.

The only extension I use for all 3 web browsers is `uBlock origin`, with default settings. I once removed this extension but it didn't change anything noticable I would say.

I see in `iotop` that whenever I access a website a few `MB` is written to disk. With my basic knowledge regarding to how web browsers work, I would say that this is the content of the website (images, files like `JavaScript`, `CSS`, etc.) which are (temporarily) written to disk. But if I disabled caching to disk why that happens? With my surfing behaviour I don't need anything stored to disk. Can a web browser keep a website content entirely in `RAM`?

My daily usual usage of the web browsers was

- 1 web browser window (mostly `Chromium`, sometimes `Opera`) for streaming video (Amazon Video, news sites, etc.), usually 1 tab is open for this
- 1 `Firefox` window and 1 `Opera` window for surfing the web, mostly in many tabs in each of the windows. In addition in `Opera` I have all my email accounts open (up to 3 tabs). `Firefox` mostly next to surfing also used for downloading any kind of files daily.

For testing purposes I now use only 1 web browser at a time but in 3 windows to achieve my daily work described above.